# Plistbuddy should not convert date format

Tags: plist

in the /Library/Preferences/com.apple.TimeMachine.plist the date format of the last backup date is in the format yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ssZ (i.e. 2022-10-31T08:43:45Z)

However, when I read this date with plistbuddy I get it back in this format:
Mon Oct 31 09:43:45 CET 2022

I want, that plistbuddy does not change the date format, I want it to get it exactly how it is in the plist. How can I achieve this? any help?

The code is:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print :Destinations:0:SnapshotDates" /Library/Preferences/com.apple.TimeMachine.plist \
    | grep ":" | tail -n1 | sed 's/^ *//g'
```

Comment: Might be easier to use `plutil` (or maybe even `defaults read`) to extract the data you need (or convert the plist into json or xml and use an appropriate parser).